# Parsing json values using jq

Tags: json, linux, bash, curl, jq

I am trying to get values "**en**" of a JSON structure using jq on the linux command line.

```
find . -name "*.json" -exec jq -r \ '(input_filename | gsub("^\\./|\\.json$";"")) as $fname (map(.tags) | .[] | .[] | .tag.en ) as $tags | "\($fname)&\($tags)"' '{}' +
```

i have more than 5000 files, start from **0001.json 0002.json .. 5000.json**

This is a simple file **0001.json**

```
{
"result": {
    "tags": [
        { "confidence": 100, "tag": { "en": "turbine" } },
        { "confidence": 64.8014373779297, "tag": { "en": "wind" } },
        { "confidence": 63.3033409118652, "tag": { "en": "generator" } },
        { "confidence": 7.27894926071167, "tag": { "en": "device" } },
        { "confidence": 7.01708889007568, "tag": { "en": "line" } }
    ]
},
"status": { "text": "", "type": "success" }
}
```

i get this result :

```
0001&turbine
0001&wind
0001&generator
0001&device
0001&line
jq: error (at ./0001.json:0): Cannot iterate over null (null)
Ouptut..
jq: error (at ./0002.json:0): Cannot iterate over null (null)
Output..
jq: error (at ./0003.json:0): Cannot iterate over null (null)
```

My Desired Output in one file from all json files results.

**filename&enValue:confidenceValue**

```
0001&turbine:100,wind:64,generator:63,device:7,line:7
0002&...
0003&...
0004&...
```

Comment: `"en"` isn't a value. `"turbine"` is. So, you're actually trying to get the value of each `"en"` attribute.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The jq filter you want can be written as follows:

```
(input_filename | gsub("^\\./|\\.json$";"")) as $fname
| ( [ .result.tags[] | [.tag.en, (.confidence | floor)] | join(":") ]
    | join(",") ) as $tags
| "\($fname)&\($tags)"
```

Comment: I'm curious... does this mean `jq` still needs to be called 5000 times?

Comment: @Reino - Who said anything about calling jq 5000 times?  The Q as posted anticipated some problem with "*.json" and envisioned using `find` with + to avoid 5000 calls to jq. Nothing's changed in that regard.

Comment: @peak, I guess it takes scrolling the question all the way to the right to see the trailing `+` sign, not everyone might get that far :)

Comment: I overlooked the `+` indeed.